# How to add external JS to CMS Page

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an external javascript file to a CMS page using the Layout Update XML feature, and have had no luck. I have tried the following

```
<action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>]]></text></action>

<action method="addJs"><script>http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0</script></action>

<action method="addItem">
<type>skin_js</type>
<name>http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0</name>
<params/>
</action>
```

The first two don't work at all, the third one adds it but prepends the skin url to the src.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks as if you haven't formatted the XML properly and it **needs to be enclosed** in a layout handle.

Here are the problems one by one:

### setText is a method for a Core Text block type

You need to put this inside of a `core/text` block for it to do anything at all:

```
<block type="core/text" name="mapcontrol.script.block">
            <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>]]></text></action>
</block>
```

### Layout instructions require a layout handle

You need to wrap these in a handle and a block reference where they'll be inserted:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/text" name="mapcontrol.script.block">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>]]></text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

### addJs is a method exclusive to Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head

You can only call it on a block of that type, e.g.:

```
<block type="page/html_head">
<action method="addJs"><file>mapcontrol/mapcontrol.js</file></action>
</block>
```

But really this is meant for local files only. This is because it attempts to prepend the type as it's really just a wrapper for `addItem`, which you then try to call again later.

### addJs calls addItem but addJs differs from the skin_js type

They're located in different places on the filesystem.

- `addJs` attempts to include from `[document_root]/js/your/file/here.js`
- `addItem` with type `skin_js` attempts to include from `[document_root]/skin/frontend/[package]/[theme]/js/your/file/here.js`

### Conclusion

To wrap up - you've made a few errors here. This should work for you and uses the setText method of a core/text block type:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/text" name="mapcontrol.script.block">
                <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>]]></text></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: Thanks guys, both worked great, I was just missing that core/text reference

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you put them all into a `<reference name="head">` element. The first one was going in the right direction, but you don't want to call `setText` on the head block itself but on a new `core/text` block.

This is the full code for the "custom layout update" of your CMS page:

```
<reference name="head">
    <block type="core/text" name="some_unique_name">
        <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script src="//ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0"></script>]]></text></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```